# summer20 feature Override Standard Actions in Lightning Communities not working in summer20 SB

Tags: lightning-community, summer20

i tried to implement this feature [summer20 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_networks_override_standard_actions.htm) in my summer 20 sandbox. but it didn't work

**steps i followed:**

1. enable "Override standard actions with a Lightning component" feature in Administration => Preferences section
   [image]
2. create custom lightning component.

   ```
   <aura:component controller="myapexController"  implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:actionOverride,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
     ***override the standard New Action on case object**
   </aura:component>
   ```
3. then override the Standard "New" Action on case object with custom lightning component.
4. checked at standard case list in community but still "new" button is not visible.
   [image]

did i miss any thing?
**Update**
once you enable all above settings , New button will be visible in recently viewed list view only, you have to do some extra settings if button needs to show up in all list views.

1. go to object manager => 2. click "search layouts for salesforce classic"
2. Edit "List view" => 4. check "New" button option in standard button List.

Then "New" button shows in all Listviews like below
[image]

But still some features are missing:

1. once New button click your component shows as modalpopup always. you can not add styles for that modal popup like (increase width & height ) in your component level.
2. work around for above problem : you can get styles if you add your styles as static resource and add your static resource in your component.
3. if you go with above work around it effects to all other modals styles.

Comment: Strange. I followed exact same steps and I am getting the override properly. Try deleting cache from chrome settings for past 1 hr and refresh.

Comment: @salesforce-sas, cleared cache multiple times but still no luck